# Jenkins job stuck on git push command

Tags: python, git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job that executes the following Windows bash commands:

```
call "C:\Users\AMRABET\Documents\VSC\Jenkins\workspace\make.bat" html
docker build --tag=dockjenk .
docker run dockjenk
del /Q "C:\Users\AMRABET\Documents\VSC\Jenkins\workspace\build\html\_sources"
xcopy /E /I C:\Users\AMRABET\Documents\VSC\Jenkins\workspace\build\html C:\Users\AMRABET\Documents\VSC\DockJenk\SphinxHTML
git reset
cd "C:\Users\AMRABET\Documents\VSC\DockJenk\"
git add SphinxHTML/
git commit -m "Documentation of Script.py in html"
git push origin master
rmdir /S /Q C:\Users\AMRABET\Documents\VSC\DockJenk\SphinxHTML\
```

Everything worked fine before (last try Friday) and I was able to see the success state of the job.

Today I wanted to retry again and unfortunately It stopped wworking. No changes have been made.

I am connecting GitHub to Jenkins using WebHook.
So I checked and the git push command is the one that get the job to stuck.

This is where it stops everytime I build the job:

[image: Result]

Any help? Thank you

I am on Windows 10.

**EDIT:**

Ok, since no one seems to be able to help me, is there any alternative method to simply push a folder to git from Jenkins?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall? Is this the public Github or some private installation? How sure are you that nothing has changed regarding the network and user authentication? Did passwords change, did ssh keys change or expire? Have you tried restarting Jenkins?

Comment: It is a public Git installation. I am dealing with my own private Git account. No passwords have been changed. i even unistall / install Jenkins. No ssh connection is needed I am working on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem was in Git **Credentials**. Somehow, they changed. I created another one with correct username and password and it worked.